# Kendo Grid Filter event doesn't work

Tags: kendo-grid

[In the demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events) provided they have shown kendo Filter event as below:

```
.Events(events => events
            .Change("onChange")
            .DataBound("onDataBound")
            .DataBinding("onDataBinding")
            .Sort("onSorting")
            .Filter("onFiltering")
            .Group("onGrouping")
            .Page("onPaging")
        )
```

But Filter event doesn't exist.
Any idea?

Comment: Link doesn't work, returning 404

Comment: please can you provide the full Grid declaration ? 
I test your code above and it is working for me.
note: did you correctly declare the js function named 'onFiltering' ?

Comment: Yes I did... But I solved using filter menu init event